# d3.js Zoomable Sunburst visualization from self-referencing CSV input

Tags: csv, d3.js, parent-child, sunburst-diagram, self-referencing-table

I'm a newbie at d3.js and need help to adapt [Zoomable Sunburst](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373) to make it work with self-referencing CSV data.
Sample lines from the input CSV:

```
id,parentId,name,size
ROOT,NULL,Root,
RE,ROOT,General > Revenue Expenditure,
RE11,RE,Main supervision recovery etc.,
RE11A109K,RE11,Shivjayanti celebrations and lighting,170000
RE11H108,RE11,Electicity for import tax naka,2550000
RE11J,RE11,Maintaince for main building,
RE11J101A,RE11J,Electricity expenditure,11475000
RE11J101 C,RE11J,Power lift,2125000
```

As you can see, there are variable levels of depth. At some places the data is coming at 3rd level, at others we might have parent-child relationships going 9 levels deep, and so on. That's government budgets for you!
While there are columns in addition to these 4 that aren't critical to the visualization (so omitted here), I would be displaying their contents in a  side pane on mouseover. So while non-critical, any additional columns do need to carry through and not get dropped.

I looked into many d3.nest() examples but those doesn't seem to work for parent-child self-referencing columns and data with variable levels of depth.

I'm presently using a workaround to convert this into hierarchical JSON in the flare.json format, using this [DataStructures.Tree project](https://github.com/stephen-james/DataStructures.Tree/) . But looking for a more direct solution. Almost there, but not able to mix up code from different sources. Would be grateful to be shown a full top-to-bottom solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. We include these scripts from the DataStructures.Tree project linked in the question : base.js, DataStructures.Tree.js. (you'll find them in /js/lib/ and /js/vendor/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataStructures.Tree.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Then, we replace this line,

```
d3.json("flare.json", functon(error, root) {
```

..with these lines:

```
d3.csv("electrical5.csv", function(data){
var tree = DataStructures.Tree.createFromFlatTable(data),
           root = tree.toSimpleObject(function(objectToDecorate, originalNode) {
                objectToDecorate.size = originalNode.size;
                if (objectToDecorate.children && objectToDecorate.children.length == 0) {
                    delete objectToDecorate.children;
                }
                return objectToDecorate;
            });
//console.log(JSON.stringify(root));
```

leave everything else just as it is.

---

Uncomment the console.log line for debugging; it will put the json code in the browser console when you load the page. You can also make a textarea in the webpage and output the json code in that.

```
document.getElementById("SHOWME").value = JSON.stringify(root);
```

[at bottom of page]

```
<textarea id="SHOWME"></textarea>
```

it will be unformatted json code, so copy-paste it to http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer and that ought to give you a well-formatted json.

---

To get more columns in apart from the regular [id,parentId,name,size] , we have to edit DataStructures.Tree.js

Locate these lines:

```
simpleChildRepresentation.push(decorateNode({
    "name" :  node.name,
    "children" : children
}, node));
```

And insert the extra columns in the same format as the node.name line.

```
simpleChildRepresentation.push(decorateNode({
    "name" :  node.name,
     //CUSTOM COLUMNS
    "workcode" : node.id,
    "parentcode" : node.parentId,
    "department" : node.department,
    "totalorextract" : node.totalorextract,
    "total" : node.total,
    "pages" : node.pages,
    //CUSTOM COLUMNS DONE
    "children" : children
}, node));
```

You can now directly visualize self-referencing csv data on any d3.js visualization that uses flare.json . Animations get a bit clunkier, though.

Answer (score 1):

An answer for something quite similar

From csv file : sample.csv

```
id,value
data,
data.aa,
data.aa.bb,
data.aa.bb.cc,123
data.aa.bb.dd,345
data.aa.ee,
data.aa.ee.ff,789
```

To

```
{
"name": "root",
"children": [{
    "name": "data",
    "children": [{
        "name": "aa",
        "children": [{
            "name": "bb",
            "children": [{
                "name": "cc",
                "children": [],
                "size": "123"
            }, {
                "name": "dd",
                "children": [],
                "size": "345"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "ee",
            "children": [{
                "name": "ff",
                "children": [],
                "size": "789"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
}
```

With this Python

```
import json
import csv

with open('sample.csv') as f:
    columns = ("id", "value")
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, columns)
    next(reader)

    json_data = {
        "name": "root",
        "children": []
    }

    for data in reader:
        current_node = json_data
        cols = data['id'].split('.')
        last_value = data['value']
        last_cell_name_with_value =  ""
        if last_value != '':
            last_cell_name_with_value = cols[len(cols)-1]
        for i in range(len(cols)):
            found_last_cell_with_value = False
            cell = cols[i]
            if cell == last_cell_name_with_value:
                found_last_cell_with_value = True
            if cell:
                found_child = False
                for child in current_node["children"]:
                    if child["name"] == cell:
                        current_node = child
                        found_child = True
                        break
                if not found_child:
                    if found_last_cell_with_value == False:
                        new_node = {
                            "name": cell,
                            "children": []
                        }
                    else:
                        new_node = {
                            "name": cell,
                            "children": [],
                            "size": last_value
                        }
                    current_node["children"].append(new_node)
                    current_node = new_node


with open('hierarchical.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(json_data, json_file)
```